# Which express templating engine should I use for simple code examples?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm writing some example code using node and express, that is targeted at beginner to intermediate front end developers (not node.js or express developers). Basically some plug and play code that allows a beginner dev to get right to the HTML, CSS and behavioral JavaScript, and host it on a simple hosting solution like Heroku.

I need a recommendation for a an express compatible templating language that is very light and simple to understand.

I need:

- Variables embedded in the template.
- Loops and if statements embedded in the template.

I want to avoid:

- Unusual syntax (Jade).
- Files that are not named .html (like
  mustache).
- Unusual looking configuration (for example to force mustache to use .html as an extension).

I need something really basic. Should I role my own, or is there a lightweight, well support third party solution I should be aware of?

Comment: maybe you can checkout this [link](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/) , since you have your own configuration.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/consolidate

Comment: if you are using [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) for any other functionality , you could use the [template](http://underscorejs.org/#template) function in that.

Comment: I decided to go with lodash templating. Thank you for the underscore suggestion. Nice, simple and lightweight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check out EJS.  It is pretty decent and fairly easy to use.  It is also compatible with Angular.  I go back and forth using EJS and Dust.

EJS is very forgiving and easy to get started.